# Not able to convert Date String to required format using MomentJS

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to convert a `Date String` of format

`Mon Dec 03 2018 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

into a format of `YYYY-MM-DD` so as to use it for a value in `input date` but it's not able to parse it.

I tried using these formats but it didn't work.

`moment(new Date(Mon Dec 03 2018 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))).format("YYYY-MM-DD")`

But since it's not a `Date.parse()` format, it doesn't work.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the dateFormat while creating the moment object, inorder for it to recognize and parse non-default formats.

Try,

```
var dateFormat = "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss zZZ";
var m = moment("Mon Dec 03 2018 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", dateFormat);

m.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

More details for parsing from string: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/